# Finite Precision DFT looks broken

Tags: fft, fourier-transform, frequency-spectrum, dft

1. I calculate the FFT of a sine wave. In Matlab I get the result as I would expect with a nice real and imaginary part. (blue is real, red is imaginary)

[image: matlab_fft]

2. Now I also calculate a FFT on a FPGA with fixed point numbers. Real and imaginary parts look completely destroyed with neighboring large negative and positive peaks.

[image: labview fft]

I have checked my input signals and they are correct.

**Question:** Why does this happen? Does it have something to do with finite precision? Is there a way to get reasonable results?

Comment: these results look *very* reasonable to me! What is your actual problem with them?

Comment: Why is there a large positive value and negative value in the imaginary part of the second picture? Why is there no single peak like in matlab?

Comment: when you compare that and the real part with your matlab plot, you'll notice that they are simply the negative of each other – I ignored that as detail. Your FPGA side signal simply has the inverse sign as your matlab signal.

Comment: Yes but why is there a huge positive peak followed by a huge negative peak in the imaginary part in the second picture but not in the fft result in matlab? Why is the real part in the second picture not a single peak?

Comment: well, because the quantized signal has quantization errors?! Plus, even a benign phase shift might do that, and we've demonstrated that we don't / can't know the phase of your sinusoids...

Comment: Can I somehow minimize this quantization error?

Comment: Yes, use finer quantization. Again, you're looking at symptoms, you don't seem to care about any problems in particular. What is the problem you're having with the quantization. Is it *really* a problem, or do you just think it is? Because, so far you're concerned about to not-identical signals not looking identical after a DFT, and IMHO, that's more than fine...

Comment: I am calculating the hadamard product (element wise multiplication) of this FFT after complex conjugation with the FFT of another signal (also a sine wave with some arbitrary phase shift) in order to do real time adaptive inverse filtering.  These quantization errors are big enough to cause the adaptive filter to diverge. The result of the IFFT of the hadamard product of the FFTs of the two sine waves should be a sine wave but its not due to this quantization errors.

Comment: um, no, quantization errors are not breaking your product here. You're caring about the wrong thing, almost certainly! There's either a logical bug in what you're doing, or a numerical bug in how you're doing it.

Comment: @Bulbasaur. You need to supply a lot more detail: How is the sine wave generated , what precisions do you have for data & twiddle factors, what's the scaling strategy in the FFT between stages, do you use higher resolution accumulators, how are the twiddle factors generated, etc. Fixed point is complicated and the details really matter

Comment: Have you ever considered to simulate the fixpoint approach in Matlab? Why are you checking the behavior on your FPGA without really getting a feeling for fixed point math in Matlab?

Comment: As people have said: try it out in Matlab. You basically have three error sources: 1) quantization of the input signal (easy to check in Matlab), 2) quantization noise, 3) finite-precision twiddle factor coefficients leading to a slightly different transform than what you expect. Increasing the word lengths should give identical results.